# Multiple JNI Layer in the same SO File.

Tags: java-native-interface, native

I am trying to add jni layer to an old library.

There is already a jni layer in that library. But I do not wish to add my code to that file.

For better management I want to create seperate java and c files.

Is it possible have "multiple" JNI Layers in the same .so file?

If so how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by multiple JNI layers.  It sounds like you are asking if you can run javah against two distinct java files and create a single JNI library based on native methods contained in those two files?  Absolutely.  Simply compile and link each file together.